# get the current element

Tags: angularjs

It's possible to intercept current event object in `ng-click` like handlers by using `$event` property.

But is it possible to get the element from which the method has been called?

like for example:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
  <div>{{distortThatDiv($element)}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm really curious about that div you're distorting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a directive in angular it is easy to access the element. Just use the **link** function:

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.directive('distortThatDiv', function distortThatDivDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
               element.on('click', function () {
                 // do something
               });
            } 
        };
    });
});
```

Your html would be:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
  <a distort-that-div>My link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Note also that if your directive returns only a function then Angular will assume it is the `link` function.

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to manipulate the DOM, you really should be using a directive. However, if you have the `$event`, you can [get the raw element the event was triggered on](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) easily:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function($event) {
   var element = $event.target;
};
```

Comment: but I'm not using $event... so there's no way to get the element itself?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. However, since the element is attached to the event, why don't you use `$event`? (Your example uses `$element`, just change it to `$event` and add a line to the click handler).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative (not sure if this is a good practice, though):

In your template:

```
<div data-ng-click="foo()">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('fooApp')
.controller('FooController', ['$scope', '$window', '$log', function FooController ($scope, $window, $log) {
    $scope.foo = function foo () {
        $log.info($window.currentTarget.innerHTML); // Outputs 'Lorem Ipsum';
    }
}]);
```